# C# Aumentar en 1 el valor de un Dictionary<int, int> con LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, diccionarios

Tengo el siguiente diccionario

```
Dictionary<int, int> datos
```

El cual contiene los siguientes clave-valor:

```
[0, 2015]
[1, 2016]
[2, 2017]
```

Mi objetivo es aumentar en 1 (**con LINQ**) el value para que quedase así:

```
[0, 2016]
[1, 2017]
[2, 2018]
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Linq no es para modificar  `IEnumerable`, en todo caso puede devolver un nuevo diccionario con la modificación que quieres. Has intentado algún codigo?

Comment: Gracias por responder, he estado buscando código pero claro no he encontrado nada (quizás por eso que comentas). Sin LINQ lo hago rápido con un for loop, pero quería probar a ver si se podía sacar con LINQ...

Comment: Mira si mi respuesta hace mas o menos lo que necesitabas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como digo en mi comentario, LINQ es un lenguaje de consultas,no de modificación. En tu caso, lo que quieres es muy sencillo siempre y cuando entiendas que la consulta LINQ te va a devolver una nueva colección. Después puedes asignar la colección nueva a la antigua:

```
var nuevosDatos = datos.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y=> y.Value + 1);
datos = nuevosDatos;
```

O directamente:

```
datos = datos.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y=> y.Value + 1);
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias.